# print specific field based on condition

Tags: shell, if-statement, awk, grep

Can someone tell me how to print the FS name which has 60% and above ?

```
dev/mapper/vg00-LogVol01
                       4062912   1620112   2233088  43% /
/dev/mapper/vg00-LogVol02
                       2031440     87412   1839172   5% /u11
/dev/mapper/vg00-LogVol04
                       8125880   5297076   2409376  69% /opt
/dev/mapper/vg00-LogVol03
                       8125880   3314648   4391804  44% /usr
/dev/mapper/vg00-LogVol13
                       4062912    740804   3112396  20% /usr/op
/dev/mapper/vg00-LogVol11
                       4062912   2515896   1337304  66% /u01
/dev/mapper/vg00-LogVol02
                       8125880   5409672   2296780  71% /var
/dev/mapper/vg00-LogVol09
                       2031440    148780   1777804   8% /var/opt
/dev/mapper/vg00-LogVol01
                       5078656   3391592   1424960  71% /tmp
```

for example : print /tmp showing 71% which is greater than 60%

Comment: What is your desired output? Have you tried anything yourself? If so, did you encounter any specific problems?

Comment: What about `/u01`, `/var`?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$4+0>=60{print l, $4}{l=$0}' input
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
awk '/%/ && int($4)>=60 {print $4, $5}' filename
```

Comment: I get the output below 43% /
5% /u11
69% /opt
44% /usr
20% /usr/op
66% /u01
71% /var
8% /var/opt
71% /tmp  need to print the FS only above 60%

Comment: My bad: **$0** should be **$4**  Changed the awk code above - sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You better use `df -P` to force `df` to output each record on one line. Once you do that `awk` is easy:

```
df -P | awk 'int($(NF-1)) >= 60 {print $1, $(NF-1)}'
```

Comment: Getting error : awk: (FILENAME=- FNR=34) fatal: attempt to access field -1

Comment: Try: `df -P | awk 'NF>2 && int($(NF-1)) >= 60 {print $1, $(NF-1)}'`